# UNIX command - clear files based on the date logic

Tags: shell, unix

--Newbie to UNIX--

I am looking for a UNIX command to remove some of the files in the directory based on date logic. Sample file structure:

```
Aug 30 01:30 Test20210830.ctl
Aug 30 01:30 Test20210830.txt
Aug  3 01:30 Test20210803.ctl
Aug  3 01:30 Test20210803.txt
Aug  2 01:30 Test20210802.ctl
Aug  2 01:30 Test20210802.txt
Aug  1 01:30 Test20210801.ctl
Aug  1 01:30 Test20210801.txt
Jul  1 01:30 Test20210701.ctl
Jul  1 01:30 Test20210701.txt
Jun 16 01:30 Test20210616.ctl
Jun 16 01:30 Test20210616.txt
Jun 15 01:30 Test20210615.ctl
Jun 15 01:30 Test20210615.txt
```

ls -ltr Test* | grep `date +%b` | head -2 -- this command gives the top 2 files that I want to keep (first 2 files of each month).
I want to remove the rest of the files from the same month (so the July and June 2 files still have to be there). There is a job that runs at end of each month so..

What is the best approach to remove the files and keep the files I want?

Comment: I would recommend using the date that's in the filenames to sort them as it's simple lexicographical order

Comment: how to do that in a script or a command? if I want to remove the rest of the files?

Comment: Please show exactly the files you want to keep

Comment: I have an idea. I'll prepare an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to keep only the first two lexicographically-sorted file*names* from each month, you could use a simple loop and shell filename expansion:

```sh
for year in 2021
do
  for month in {01..12}
  do
    set -- Test${year}${month}*
    if [ "$#" -gt 2 ]
    then
      shift 2
      echo would rm -- "$@"
    fi
  done
done
```

Note that this would remove `Test20210616.ctl` and `Test20210616.txt` as it's specifically shifting off the first *two* filenames of each month.

The core part of this script is in the `set` and `shift 2` portions. The `set -- Test${year}${month}*` line expands the year and month variables and appends the `*` wildcard to match any/all filenames that start with "Test" followed by the loop's current year and month values. Once those filenames are expanded -- or not! -- they are available in the special `$@` array variable. Note that if there are no matches, there will be one value in the array -- the unexpanded "Test"... wildcard. This *would* be a special-case to watch out for if we needed to know if there was one *actual* filename match, but here we're only interested in the situation where there are more than two matches. The resulting filenames, if any, are added to the array in lexicographic order.

Once the filenames are in `$@`, the `shift 2` simply pops the first two elements off the front of the list -- here, the first two filenames (sorted lexicographically). What remains is one or more filenames that are candidates to be removed.

Remove the `echo would` in order to enable this, if the results look correct.

Comment: do yuo mind explaining the command? for each just add description what it does?   This part specifically:        
 set -- Test${year}${month}*
    if [ "$#" -gt 2 ]
    then
      shift 2
      echo would rm -- "$@"

Comment: So if I dont want year in this logic I can just remove the year part and keep the month right? something like this:  for month in {01..12}
  do
    set -- Test*${month}*
    if [ "$#" -gt 2 ]
    then
      shift 2
      echo would rm -- "$@"
    fi
  done

Comment: I suppose you *could* remove the year, but the filenames in the question have the year in them, so that's why I included them in the answer.

Comment: yeah right.. I would want them to get replaced every year thats why I will play around with the script - will try and update!

Answer (score 0):

I have put your provided input in a file called `input`.

This code is safe to run as it doesn't actually remove the file but you can see the output for yourself. It tells you which file would be removed and which would stay with some self-explanatory lines at the end of each section.

It simply counts how many times it have seen the month so far and if it's more than two it outputs `removing file`. Otherwise it prints `file stays!`.

Output attached below.

```
lastmon=""
counter=0

# replace "cat input" with your "ls -l" or so
cat input | egrep -o "\S+$" | sort -r | # extract filenames
  for filename in $(cat)
  do
    # extract pieces from filename
    echo "filename: $filename"
    echo -n "date: "
    echo $filename | egrep -o '[0-9]+'
    echo -n "month: "
    echo $filename | egrep -o '[0-9]+' | cut -b5-6 
    
    # compare month to last month
    mon="$(echo $filename | egrep -o '[0-9]+' | cut -b5-6)"
    if [ "x$mon" != "x$lastmon" ]
    then counter=0
    fi
    lastmon="$mon"
    
    # keep counting
    counter=$((counter+1))
    echo counter: $counter 

    # if more than two in a row decide to remove file
    if [ $counter -gt 2 ]
    then echo result: removing file
    else echo result: file stays!
    fi
    
    echo # print empty line
  done
```

Output

```
filename: Test20210830.txt                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         [39/1872]
date: 20210830                                                         
month: 08                                                              
counter: 1                                                             
file stays!                                                            
                                                                       
filename: Test20210830.ctl                                             
date: 20210830                                                         
month: 08                                                              
counter: 2                                                             
file stays!                                                            
                                                                       
filename: Test20210803.txt                                             
date: 20210803                                                         
month: 08                                                              
counter: 3                                                             
removing file                                                          
                                                                       
filename: Test20210803.ctl                                             
date: 20210803                                                         
month: 08                                                              
counter: 4                                                             
removing file                                                          
                                                                       
filename: Test20210802.txt                                             
date: 20210802                                                         
month: 08                                                              
counter: 5                                                             
removing file                                                          
                                                                       
filename: Test20210802.ctl                                             
date: 20210802                                                         
month: 08                                                              
counter: 6                                                             
removing file                                                          
                                                                       
filename: Test20210801.txt                                             
date: 20210801                                                         
month: 08                                                              
counter: 7                                                             
removing file                                                          

filename: Test20210801.ctl                                             
date: 20210801                                                         
month: 08                                                              
counter: 8                                                             
removing file       

filename: Test20210701.txt                                             
date: 20210701                                                         
month: 07                                                              
counter: 1                                                             
file stays!                                                            

filename: Test20210701.ctl                                             
date: 20210701                                                         
month: 07                                                              
counter: 2                                                             
file stays!                                                            

filename: Test20210616.txt                                             
date: 20210616                                                         
month: 06                                                              
counter: 1                                                             
file stays!                                                            

filename: Test20210616.ctl                                             
date: 20210616                                                         
month: 06                                                              
counter: 2                                                             
file stays!                                                            

filename: Test20210615.txt                                             
date: 20210615                                                         
month: 06                                                              
counter: 3                                                             
removing file                                                          

filename: Test20210615.ctl                                             
date: 20210615                                                         
month: 06                                                              
counter: 4                                                             
removing file
```